# AlarmManager isn't working in correct schedule

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

In my app, i have 18 `Checkboxes` and if the user check it, the `AlarmManager` will start a notification in the time that `CheckBox` indicates. I tested the `AlarmManager` with just one alarm, and it works correctly.

But when i added all the schedules, it's not working correctly and the `AlarmManager` is starting the notification in an aleatory time, usually when i close the app.

**MainFragment.class**, in method `onCreate`. This is to save that the checkbox is marked and to call the method that will create the AlarmManager.

```
// isChecked?
        checkBoxesEvents.get(0).setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                savePreferences(0);
                if(isChecked) {
                    startAlarm(0);
                }
            }
        });
        checkBoxesEvents.get(1).setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                savePreferences(1);
                if(isChecked) {
                    startAlarm(1);
                }
            }
        });
        checkBoxesEvents.get(2).setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                savePreferences(2);
                if(isChecked) {
                    startAlarm(2);
                }
            }
        });
        checkBoxesEvents.get(3).setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                savePreferences(3);
                if(isChecked) {
                    startAlarm(3);
                }
            }
        });
        checkBoxesEvents.get(4).setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                savePreferences(4);
                if(isChecked) {
                    startAlarm(4);
                }
            }
        });
        checkBoxesEvents.get(5).setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                savePreferences(5);
                if(isChecked) {
                    startAlarm(5);
                }
            }
        });
        checkBoxesEvents.get(6).setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                savePreferences(6);
                if(isChecked) {
                    startAlarm(6);
                }
            }
        });
        checkBoxesEvents.get(7).setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                savePreferences(7);
                if(isChecked) {
                    startAlarm(7);
                }
            }
        });
        checkBoxesEvents.get(8).setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                savePreferences(8);
                if(isChecked) {
                    startAlarm(8);
                }
            }
        });
        checkBoxesEvents.get(9).setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                savePreferences(9);
                if(isChecked) {
                    startAlarm(9);
                }
            }
        });
        checkBoxesEvents.get(10).setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                savePreferences(10);
                if(isChecked) {
                    startAlarm(10);
                }
            }
        });
        checkBoxesEvents.get(11).setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                savePreferences(11);
                if(isChecked) {
                    startAlarm(11);
                }
            }
        });
        checkBoxesEvents.get(12).setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                savePreferences(12);
                if(isChecked) {
                    startAlarm(12);
                }
            }
        });
        checkBoxesEvents.get(13).setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                savePreferences(13);
                if(isChecked) {
                    startAlarm(13);
                }
            }
        });
        checkBoxesEvents.get(14).setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                savePreferences(14);
                if(isChecked) {
                    startAlarm(14);
                }
            }
        });
        checkBoxesEvents.get(15).setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                savePreferences(15);
                if(isChecked) {
                    startAlarm(15);
                }
            }
        });
        checkBoxesEvents.get(16).setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                savePreferences(16);
                if(isChecked) {
                    startAlarm(16);
                }
            }
        });
        checkBoxesEvents.get(17).setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                savePreferences(17);
                if(isChecked) {
                    startAlarm(17);
                }
            }
        });
```

**MainFragment.class**, this is the method to create the Alarm.

```
public void startAlarm(int eventID) {
        int[] HOUR_ARRAY =      {7, 20, 7,12,17 ,8,16, 8, 9,21, 9,19,12,13,13,14,15,15};
        int[] MINUTES_ARRAY =   {55,55,55,55,55,25,25,55,55,55,55,25,50,25,55,55,25,55};
        String[] NOTIFICATION_TITLES = {"Ocleera Rift", "Ocleera Rift", "Mistmerrow Conflict", "Mistmerrow Conflict",
        "Mistmerrow Conflict", "Freedich Gold Trader", "Freedich Gold Trader", "Nation Construction Quests", "Diamond Shores",
        "Diamond Shores", "Battle of the Golden Plains", "Battle of the Golden Plains", "Karkasse Ridgelands", "Kraken",
        "The Mirage Isle Fish Fest", "Red Dragon", "Abyssal Attack", "Lusca Awakening"};

        String notificationTitle = getString(R.string.contentTitle);
        String notificationText = NOTIFICATION_TITLES[eventID] + getString(R.string.contentNotificationText);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        Log.d("HOUR-BEFORE-SET", String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)) + String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE)));
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, HOUR_ARRAY[eventID]);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, MINUTES_ARRAY[eventID]);
        Log.d("HOUR-AFTER-SET", String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)) + String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE)));

        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra("contentTitle", notificationTitle);
        intent.putExtra("contentText", notificationText);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), eventID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
    }
```

**AlarmReceiver.class**, and this is my `BroadcastReceiver`

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context
        .NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent repeatingIntent = new Intent(context,RepeatingActivity.class);
        repeatingIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,100,repeatingIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        String contentTitle = intent.getStringExtra("contentTitle");
        String contentText = intent.getStringExtra("contentText");

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_notification)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.icon_notification))
                .setContentTitle(contentTitle)
                .setContentText(contentText)
                .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                .setVibrate(new long[]{800,500,600,300})
                .setLights(Color.GREEN, 500, 500)
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        notificationManager.notify(100,builder.build());

        // Light up the screen
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        boolean isScreenOn = false;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
            isScreenOn = pm.isInteractive();
        }
        else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH){
            isScreenOn = pm.isScreenOn();
        }

        if(isScreenOn==false)
        {
            PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK |PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP |PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE,"MyLock");
            wl.acquire(10000);
            PowerManager.WakeLock wl_cpu = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,"MyCpuLock");

            wl_cpu.acquire(10000);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AlarmManager documentation says about `setRepeating`:

> If the stated trigger time is in the past, the alarm will be triggered
>   immediately, with an alarm count depending on how far in the past the
>   trigger time is relative to the repeat interval.

My alarm was starting in wrong time because the time set is already passed. And have no relation with the multiple alarms.

What i did to adjust it was put the alarm that has passed, to start just in the next day.

```
Calendar actualTime = Calendar.getInstance();
if(calendar.getTimeInMillis() < actualTime.getTimeInMillis()) {
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
}
```

I just added it to my code.